# Any person convicted of a violation of this section shall forfeit to the United States irrespective of any provision of State law

Tags: word-usage, legalese

Context: http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/794

> Any person convicted of a violation of this section shall forfeit to
>   the United States irrespective of any provision of State law

What does it mean "State law" here?

Is it mean USA's law or it means law of country where person is situeted?

Comment: "For the purposes of this subsection, the term “State” includes a [State of the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._state), the District of Columbia, and any commonwealth, territory, or possession of the United States."

Comment: My bad, I miss this continuation. What exactly does it means "shall forfeit to the United States". I've think that shall be delivered(extradited) to the USA.

Comment: Look, e.g. Snowden, He is in Russia, He shall forfeit to the United States irrespective of any provision of State law, but with respect to law of Russia he will not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions and followups may be answered by examining the context:

> **(d)**
>
> > **(1)** Any person convicted of a violation of this section shall forfeit to the United States irrespective of any provision of State law—
> >
> > > (A) any property constituting, or derived from, any proceeds the person obtained, directly or indirectly, as the result of such violation, and
> > >       (B) any of the person’s property used, or intended to be used, in any manner or part, to commit, or to facilitate the commission of, such violation.
> >
> > For the purposes of this subsection, the term “State” includes a State of the United States, the District of Columbia, and any commonwealth, territory, or possession of the United States.

*State*, as Tyler James Young points out, is defined in the second sentence. The base sense of *State* here is one of the fifty states which comprise the United States, which is the normal sense of the word in US law; the second sentence here is put in to extend the interpretation to include the District of Columbia, where the country's capitol city is located, and other territories and possessions of the US.

Each state of the United States makes its laws about matters in which the national government (the Federal government) is not involved. Nonetheless, a state's laws might have incidental provisions which conflict with a Federal statute; for instance, a state's constitution or statutes might protect certain classes of property from legal forfeiture. This subsection of the Federal statute provides expressly that any such State law shall be of no force in determining what property shall be forfeited.

Notice that the fragment you quote is not a complete sentence. *Forfeit* is a transitive verb meaning give up SOMETHING to SOMEBODY as a penalty. Here, the SOMEBODY is the United States; the SOMETHING is the property described in sections A and B which follow this sentence fragment and complete it. Reduced to its simplest form, the sentence has the structure:

> Any person convicted ... shall forfeit to the United States ... (A) and (B)

This is not the usual order. Ordinarily we would say "...shall forfeit A and B to the United States". The legislature constructs the sentence this way in order to make the structure clearer. This is very common in legal writing.